# Chrome App OAuth 2.0 Client saying "Sorry, something went wrong there, try again."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-chrome-app

I developed a chrome extension. It is currently published - unlisted and using a **Google OAuth 2.0 Client that is in testing and not verified**. All my test users have been whitelisted/added to in the console to have access. The app upon first time opening it has the consent screen come up and the users needs to hit allow to get their Chrome Token with `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`. However, a few users are reporting that a Google popup appears and will ask them to choose their Google Account and then once they choose it the screen then just says **"Sorry, something went wrong there, try again."**, and `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` is returning `undefined`. This should not be happening.

The user should select account and `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` should return their chrome token and they should not be prompted again for this unless they sign out or delete account etc.

Screenshots Below 
[Sign in Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJqsE.png)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QAQN.png)

Comment: I am having the same issues for a Google Data Studio Community Connector. The publishing status is set to "Testing" and I've whitelisted users but they are getting the same message.

Did you file the bug in another forum? Let me know and I'll upvote for visibility.

Comment: So how did you solve it in the end?